# Dynamic page breadcrumb implementation with ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, breadcrumbs

I would like to dynamically render page breadcrumbs for a property page. It should look this way:

`Home > Country name > City name > Property name`.

The name of the country, city and property are retrieved from database using the property id. I have no issues with the query, but how do I pass the values to the view?

Below is my config site map: It only returns Home > Property

```
 return [
         'navigation' => [
            'default' => [
               'home' => [
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home-page',
                'pages' => [
                    'property-page' => [
                        'label' => 'Property',
                        'module' => 'application',
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Property',
                        'route' => 'property-page',
                        'action' => 'index'
                      ],
                    ],
                 ],
               ],
             ],
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do that by the `navigation` to your `service config`. Something like this :

```
'navigation' => function($sm) {
               $navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;
               $navigation = $navigation->createService($sm);
 
                //add here other staff for the navigation
  
 }
```

And then, when you fetch items from database, you can change the `navigation` just like this :

```
$navigation = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('navigation'); //get the navigation
$page = $nav->findByLabel('country')->setLabel($country); //set country value as label
```

Where `$country` is the fetched value of country proprety.

You could see this [post](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/zend-framework-2-dynamic-navigation-using-zend-navigation/) and this [one](http://www.jaapsblog.nl/blog/view/35/zf2-creating-a-dynamic-navigation.html) for more details.